# Rails 5 and Heroku: can't do "heroku run rake db:migrate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku. I'm in final step where I try to do `heroku run rake db:migrate` however there is this error in terminal:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `precompile' for #<Myapp::Application:0x007fcd3325a938>
Did you mean?  precompiled_assets
/app/config/environments/production.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
/app/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:193:in `public_send'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:193:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

In my application.rb I have:

```
config.assets.precompile += [ 'appviews.css', 'cssanimations.css', ...#other stuff
config.assets.precompile += [ 'appviews.js', 'cssanimations.js', ...#other stuff
```

I tried to move these `precompile` lines to config/environmens/development.rb but it did not help. **I'm a bit confused, how to fix this, please? Thank you!**

**Update**

Here is what I have in production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do

  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "adsales_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
    if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
    end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I don't understand why error is pointing to `Myapp::Application` which is in *myapp/config/application.rb*

Comment: please post `production.rb`

Comment: something wrong at `app/config/environments/production.rb:3`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Please, see it in Update above.

Comment: Check the edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You need to remove this line from your `production.rb` which is causing the issue.

Also, this line doesn't belong to this file. You need to run this command manually to precompile the assets. Heroku does this for you.

---

**Configuration**

The configuration is changed in rails 5

Add this in `production.rb`

```
# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true

# `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb
```

You need to add the following in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

Comment: Thank you, however it did not help - error stays the same. Can you check my production.rb in Update above, please?

Comment: Thank you, it worked - it did db:migrate. I see dyno is working, but app is not opened in browser. In logs it says `2017-01-25T17:14:47.222654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=ececeadd-a441-46a1-8b30-ccc023d5935d fwd="78.84.173.112" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=` Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: once `heroku run rake db:migrate` is done restart the dynos

Comment: I tried to restart, it show status `started` and then I see it is `crashed`. I even did not refresh app.